# Does the FreeNAS target make use of iSCSI offload cards?

Tags: iscsi, truenas, tcp-offload-engine

When using a [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org) as [iSCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iscsi) target, would it use the iSCSI offload engine on cards that have it, or is it an initiator-only feature?

For clarification, I want to know if a *supported* iSCSI offload card will also give me benefit when used with FreeNAS/FreeBSD's *iSCSI target*, or if it does only "kick in" for *iSCSI initiator* usage.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your NIC/s - FreeNAS is based on BSD, so whatever the version of BSD underlies the version of FreeNAS you have dictates whether your specific NIC will allow this support.

Basically drop to a command prompt, find out what BSD version you have, then find out what NIC you have and do a spot of googling for the two - you may find some instructions on this support such as [THIS](http://forum.broadcom.com/showthread.php?2452-BCM5709-support-on-FreeBSD) one for a particular Broadcom NIC.

Comment: I *do know* which iSCSI NICs are supported by FreeBSD / FreeNAS, but the docs always talk about iSCSI *initiator* offload. I want to know if a *supported* card will be used also for *target* offload. I'll clarify this in my question.